# How can i make DatePickerFor a readonly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

i have the DatePickerFor and i want to make it readonly I want to force user to pick dates ,not being able to type them.

```
<td>@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.DateRecherche).Max(DateTime.Today))</td>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it in [their docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/how-to/readonly-input):

```
//DISABLE inputs
$("#datepicker").attr("readonly", true);
$("#monthpicker").attr("readonly", true);
```

So you will need a little bit of javascript along with your view code to implement this behavior

Comment: i'm asking for if i can an attribute int the same line to add readonly

Comment: @HamzaElgarni, I suppose you could try using "HtmlAttributes": `.HtmlAttributes(new { @readonly="readonly" })`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the attribute `readonly` to an input tag will make it read only. You can do this with jQuery like this:

```
$(function () {
        $('.k-datepicker input').attr('readonly', 'true');
    });
```

Comment: This works for kendo monthPicker. both IE and Chrome.Thanks